# Java: Weird behaviour during white space seperation of a String

Tags: java

I have 2 Strings. I am trying to understand why the "test" String that contains a sequence of numbers with a white space is ignored by the test.split(); function while the "test2" is working as expected.

```
    String test = "2 703,8";
    String test2 = "bla bla 2 703,8";

    String[] tests = test.split("\\s+");

    for (String s : tests) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    String[] tests2 = test2.split("\\s+");

    for (String s : tests2) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

[image]

What I am actually trying to do is somehow make the number "2 703,8" appear without the space. I have tried to use the replaceAll(); function but that did not work.

Comment: Works fine for me with the code you posted. You're likely to have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I executed your code and it works fine. Check the character between 2 and 703,8. Perhaps it is not a whitespace? Replace the character by deleting it and typing space. Try again afterwards

Comment: I am using java 8 and I really cant make it work maybe that is the case? Iam pretty sure Iam using the space because I copied the code from my IDE here...

Comment: looking like your IDE is sick.

Comment: Maybe that is the problem I have Eclipse Neon.

Comment: You're sure you've got a whitespace between the two numbers?

Comment: @Thomas I am sure, also I am printing the length of the "test" String and the result is 7 which means it can see that there is something there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing (a) the length of the string and (b) it exact contents, character by character.

It's likely that either there is a hidden character preventing the match (such as a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)) or the character that looks like a space is actually some other blank character that Java doesn't consider whitespace.

If looking at the exact characters in the string reveals nothing, I'd guess you have a typo in your actual regex that being included here. For example `\\s\\s+` would mean there has to be *more than* one space.

Comment: Thank you a: the length is 7 b:the content seems to be "2&#160;703,8" which means that &#160; is a non-breaking space. By replacing that with an empty String works. -> test.replaceAll("&#160;", "");

Answer (score 0):

Copy the space between 2 and 7 and paste it in a cell in excel; for example in the cell A1, and then in cell A2 type =CODE(A1). If the result is 32 it is a normal space if not then it is something else (for e.g. a non breaking space if the result is 160)